# Bizarre error when trying to connect to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, localhost

Over the last day or so I'm not able to connect to a database through PHP. Here's what my code connecting to the database looks like

`$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","database");` 
And here's the strange error.

> PHP Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in - on line 2

I'd usually get that error if the credentials are incorrect, but I used a GUI and tested the connection with the *exact* credentials, where therefore means that, that is not the issue. I just started randomly getting this error and have restarted my computer, reinstalled MySQL, and reconfigure the server I've also tried `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`  I'm on `localhost` so I have full control on pretty much anything and I didn't mess with anything causing this issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the function is trying to connect using the "user" user instead of "root".

You can debug further by adding the error link:

`$con= mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con))`;

Comment: You code have a typo...it should be mysqli_error($con) instead of mysqli_error($link)

Comment: I mean `PHP Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in - on line 2 PHP Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in - on line 2`

Comment: sorry quickly copied and pasted. have now edited the post. Did you get a better error?

Comment: can you please paste the connection as it is. I assume that you are passing the connection data as variables and that one of them is returning 0/1 (boolean) instead of the value.

Comment: Here it is `$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","alistar123","s") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: sorry to ask but is your db name "s". Also can you check and make sure that it exists as I cannot see anything wrong in your connection string and I assume that root has enough priviliges on the database.

Comment: Yes it is `s`. I've also been able to connect to it through a GUI successfully. And yes root has enough privileges

Comment: can you try using: `$con= new mysqli('localhost','root','alistar123','s');` worked on a linux box.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in mysql server configuration.

You can try to change password and after flush privileges.

Than restart mysql!

Hope this helps! Bye.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as the title of this question, so incase anyone else googles upon this question and wants to start MySql in 'skip-grant-tables' mode on Windows, here is what I did.

Stop the MySQL service through Administrator tools, Services.

Modify the my.ini configuration file (assuming default paths)

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini
```

In the SERVER SECTION, under [mysqld], add the following line:

```
skip-grant-tables
```

so that you have

```
# SERVER SECTION
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#The following options will be read by the MySQL Server. Make sure that
# you have installed the server correctly (see above) so it reads this 
# file.
#
[mysqld]

skip-grant-tables
```

Start the service again and you should be able to log into your database without a password.